# Asterisk with FastAgi + Remote PC (Windows) PHP file

Tags: php, windows, asterisk, remote-access, fastagi

I am a newbie to asterisk and found it really interesting! I've been able to create a dial plan that works perfect, but, I am stuck on working with FastAgi. I want asterisk to run my PHP script that is placed on my windows server remote machine. I have called fast AGI as show below:

```
exten => s,n,AGI(agi://192.168.0.101/tts.php?number=123456789&pin=123)
```

But asterisk CLI always shows `Connection refused` or `Connection refused for the url 192.168.0.101:4573/tts.php?number=123456789&pin=123`

I wonder why is it appending the port by its own.

Need help to go through this Connection refusing thing, I have tried turning off the fire wall but still failure.

P.S: My PHP script is a simple one like the normal PHP script, nothing special.

Thank You in advanced

Comment: Asterisk has a rather wide range of default ports, what's the model of phone you're trying to connect to?

Comment: I am simply placing the call from my smart phone. I am able to listen the voices and follow the dial plan as required, but when it comes to this tcp connection step it simply prints on the CLI "Connection refused" and the call hangs up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the question by my self. The only problem was that default port "4573" as my remote PC was not configured to listen this port. Any how, I solved it by simply adding a port to my IP like this "IP:80" and the connection was complete with response of 0.

Any how the script never fired after this so I use CURL function to get my php script running.

Thank You